# Need help solving an error with heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm building an app and trying to deploy to heroku however recieving an Application error after deployment:

```
2019-01-26T02:53:35.662291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=project-beatbox.herokuapp.com request_id=61938c44-6bd4-4534-81a3-45485a5d4320 fwd="24.46.195.233" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-26T03:02:44.607316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-01-26T03:02:48.676331+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-01-26T03:02:51.553420+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-26T03:02:51.553442+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2019-01-26T03:02:51.553444+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2019-01-26T03:02:51.553445+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-26T03:02:49.836012+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user tmjohnson1214@gmail.com
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784326+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:90
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784383+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err0;
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784386+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784388+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784390+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/temp'
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784392+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:890:18)
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784393+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.sync (/app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784395+00:00 app[web.1]: at new DiskStorage (/app/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:21:12)
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784397+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:65:10)
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784398+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Multer (/app/node_modules/multer/index.js:15:20)
2019-01-26T03:02:52.784400+00:00 app[web.1]: at multer (/app/node_modules/multer/index.js:95:12)
```

Comment: Any code you may have would be helpful

Comment: Make sure you don't have any nodemons in your scripts

Comment: `Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/temp'` do not use `/temp`